# PLSQL apresenta erro: PLS-00487: Invalid referencia to variabel

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho um código PLSQL: no qual recebo dois valores um numérico e outro varchar.

**Codigo:**

```
create or replace FUNCTION hospitalTeste123(MatriculaMedico in number,  nomeSchema in varchar2 ) return varchar is

  type Tmedicos is record( 
    matMedico     nomeSchema.Tmedico.matricula%type, 
    especialidade nomeSchema.Tmedico.especialidade%type,
    cd_setor      nomeSchema.Tmedico.cd_setor%type
  );  

medico Tmedicos;

begin

  medico.matMedico       := 123;
  medico.especialidade   := 'geral';
  medico.cd_setor        := 'urgencia';

 RETURN medico.MatMedico;
end;
```

**Script de Criação das Tabelas**

```
 create table TMedico(
  matMedico     number(10) NOT NULL,
  especialidade varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  cd_setor      varchar2(50) NOT NULL
 );

insert into TMedico(matMedico,especialidade,cd_setor) Values (120,'clinico-geral','UTI');
insert into TMedico(matMedico,especialidade,cd_setor) Values (150,'cardiologista','UTI');
insert into TMedico(matMedico,especialidade,cd_setor) Values (180,'pediatria','UTI');
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> PLS-00487: Invalid referencia to variabel 'nomeSchema'
>
> Erro(3,3): PL/SQL: Item ignored Erro(4,19): PLS-00487: Invalid
>   reference to variable 'NOMESCHEMA' Erro(13,3): PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored Erro(13,10): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this
>   expression is incomplete or malformed Erro(14,3): PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored Erro(14,10): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this
>   expression is incomplete or malformed Erro(15,3): PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored Erro(15,10): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this
>   expression is incomplete or malformed Erro(17,2): PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored Erro(17,16): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this
>   expression is incomplete or malformed

O erro esta quando passo o nome do schema na qual a tabela esta gravada. 
Como cada hospital tem um Schema diferente.

**Imagem do tabela com Schema**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Chamando a função**

```
declare

begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(hospitalTeste123(123,'dbamv')); 
end;
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: linha 4, coluna 24: PLS-00905: object
>   DBAMV.HOSPITALTESTE123 is invalid ORA-06550: linha 4, coluna 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: A referencia que tu tá usando para fazer esse type, é uma tabela valida? Tenta tirar o nome do schema e declarar Tmedico.matricula%type

Comment: Outra coisa, chegou a conferir se tu tem grant nessas tabelas?

Comment: Esta valido. A questão é que existe um schema para cada hospital

Comment: Tenho sim autorização para gravar nas tabelas

Comment: A grande questão é tornar essa procedure generica

Comment: Como cada hospital tem um schema e passo ela por referencia, assim cada medico pode ser registrado em um hospital diferente

Comment: Entendi. A chamada estaria correta, penso que seja algo na liberação do acesso do schema para a tabela

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77480/discussion-between-alexjosesilva-and-diego).

Comment: Não existe um OWNER chamado nomeSchema no servidor. Existe?

Comment: A tabela existe. Postei a foto com schema dela

Comment: Não é possível fazer esta implementação passando por parâmetro o owner em um varchar2, pois o oracle não consegue garantir que existirá estas definições de tabela vindo de uma string, logo não consegue compilar.  O que você pode fazer é criar uma type global em um User que todos os outros users teriam grant de acesso e utilizar este type para sua função, assim garantindo a estrutura necessária.

Comment: Poderiam mim dar exemplo desta implementação @Confundir ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva, posso sim, mas primeiro me tire mais uma duvida sobre a estrutura que você esta trabalhando. Pelo que entendi você tem a mesma tabela em cada schema, porem você quer acessar esta mesma tabela em outro schema, correto? Não seria mais viável ter um schema "Template" com a definição desta tabela (Já que todas precisam estar iguais) e criar a função neste mesmo user?

Comment: Uma tabela porém com schemas diferentes. A sua sugestão é bem vinda porém não posso alterar o sistema. Encontrei ele assim.

Comment: @Confundir aguardo seu exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme falado nos comentários, já que uma reestruturação da forma de trabalho não é possível, eu vou propor duas soluções, uma mais simples e menos dinâmica e outra dinâmica, mas que vai ser bem chata de dar manutenção.

1) Criar uma Type com as mesmas definições das tabelas e utilizar esta na sua função.

Ex:

```
create or replace type Tmedicos as Object(
    matMedico     varchar(10),
    especialidade varchar(50),
    cd_setor      varchar(50)
  );

create or replace FUNCTION hospitalTeste123(MatriculaMedico in number,  nomeSchema in varchar2 ) return varchar is

   medico Tmedicos;

begin
  medico := TMedicos('123', 'geral', 'urgencia');

  :Retorno := medico.MatMedico;
end;
```

Não é a solução mais dinâmica do mundo, mas já que o PL/SQL é uma linguagem compilada, você não consegue ter este dinamismo passando o owner por parâmetro. Esta opção vai ser muito performática, porem qualquer mudança nas definições da sua tabela, precisavam ser replicados na type.

2) Tratar tudo com execute immediate, passando um parâmetro de saída para retornar o resultado de desejado.

Ex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hospitalTeste123(MatriculaMedico in number,  nomeSchema in varchar2 ) return varchar is

  retorno varchar2(10);
  Script CLOB;
begin
  Script := 'Declare' || chr(10) ||
            '  type Tmedicos is record(' || chr(10) ||
            '    matMedico     :USER.Tmedico.MatMedico%type,' || chr(10) ||
            '    especialidade :USER.Tmedico.especialidade%type,' || chr(10) ||
            '    cd_setor      :USER.Tmedico.cd_setor%type' || chr(10) ||
            '  );' || chr(10) ||
            '' || chr(10) ||
            '  medico Tmedicos;' || chr(10) ||
            '' || chr(10) ||
            'begin' || chr(10) ||
            '' || chr(10) ||
            '  medico.matMedico       := 123;' || chr(10) ||
            '  medico.especialidade   := ''geral'';' || chr(10) ||
            '  medico.cd_setor        := ''urgencia'';' || chr(10) ||
            '' || chr(10) ||
            ' :Retorno := medico.MatMedico;' || chr(10) ||
            'end;';
  Script := Replace(Script, ':USER', nomeSchema);

  execute immediate Script
    using out retorno; 

  RETURN retorno;
end;
```

Esta opção é a mais dinâmica possível, porem é muito trabalhoso dar manutenção e vai ser mais lenta, porem teria o dinamismo de trabalhar com vários owners. Uma opção para melhorar a manutenção, seria criar uma tabela que armazene o script.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Você mim ajudou bastante. Fico devendo uma.