# Como passar o schema por paramentro no PLSQL?

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma função que recebe um valor em varchar2 com o nome do Schema para no fim gravar o dado no banco porém no schema informado.

```
create or replace FUNCTION hospitalTeste123(MatriculaMedico in number,  nomeSchema in varchar2 ) return varchar is

    MATMEDICO nomeSchema.Tmedico.MATMEDICO%type;

begin

 /*corpo da função*/
 RETURN MatriculaMedico||''||nomeSchema;

end;
```

**Mensagem de erro:**

> Erro(4,11): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'NOMESCHEMA'

De que forma é possível passar o schema na função ?

Comment: Não tem como usar o nome do *schema* diretamente na delcaração de variáveis dessa forma. Para usar a variável no corpo da função, você precisará montar as consultas/comandos em *strings* e executá-las dinamicamente com [DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_sql.htm#BABBFFFJ) ou [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)

Comment: Minha pretensão é torna esse função genérica para todos schemas no banco

Comment: Para torná-la genérica, todas as consultas precisam ser dinâmicas, montadas em tempo de execução a partir de *strings*

Comment: Poderia compartilhar um exemplo ?

Comment: Não tenho Oracle instalado aqui para testar, mas é algo do tipo: `a := 'SELECT x INTO y FROM ' || nomeSchema || '.Tmedico.' || nomeMedico;` e depois: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a;` **ou** `crd = dbms_sql.parse(a); cre = dbms_sql.execute(crd);`. Isso é só um exemplo, consulte a documentação para detalhes desses comandos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui passar o schema usando um artificio dentro do PLSQL.

```
create or replace FUNCTION hospitalTeste124(MatriculaMedico in number,  nomeSchema in varchar2 ) return varchar is

     retorno varchar2(10);
     Script CLOB;
begin
 Script := 'Declare' || chr(10) ||
           'MATMEDICO '||nomeSchema||'.Tmedico.MATMEDICO%type;' || chr(10) ||
           'begin'|| chr(10) ||
           'matmedico:= '||MatriculaMedico||';'|| chr(10) ||
           ':Retorno:=matmedico;'|| chr(10) ||
           'end;';

 /*corpo da função*/

  execute immediate Script
    using out retorno; 

 RETURN retorno||'-'||nomeSchema;

end;
```

Esta resposta foi elaborada a partir  desta postagem:

> [PLSQL apresenta erro: PLS-00487: Invalid referencia to variabel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298776/plsql-apresenta-erro-pls-00487-invalid-referencia-to-variabel)